# Git on windows :|

Tags: windows, git

i've been experimenting with git as my personal code rep.. and it has been a bit of a disaster with windows.

i've used Subversion, CVS, and Perforce in the past.. none were as annoying to use as git.

i've figured out the PGP part (for github), although my workstation no longer lets me check in, and after searching around it turns out that git bash is using putty which is not that reliable and should be configured with something else..

i was not able to configure it with windows shell extension for a nice visual of what is part of the repository, what is modified, and easy check ins, and easy pushes..

has anyone successfully configured some kind of windows shell client and can efficiently and quickly synchronize various machines?

It just seems to be more pain to use than it is worth..

Comment: Since your question doesn't appear to be about http://github.com (the website), I've changed "github" to "git" to better reflect that you're asking questions about [Git](http://git-scm.com) on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I use http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ to great success. I get a nice cygwin bash shell. And even `git gui` works just fine.

I avoid all shell extensions (except for git-bash shell here, which is trivial) the vast majority of easy things can be achieved from `git gui` and `gitk`

Comment: +1. Never had a problem using msysgit.

Comment: +1 me either. except the usual line ending issues that you get with cross platform development.

Comment: @Evan yerp I forgot to mention that, the line ending one can bite you hard big time.

Comment: msysgit works great. I particularily like the fact that they have a "portable" version, as I have an aversion to installing things.

Comment: I've been using [SmartGit](http://www.shareit.com/affiliate.html?affiliateid=200142144&publisherid=200020344&target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.syntevo.com%2Fsmartgit%2Findex.html) for three years... it does everything I've needed. If you're having trouble using the command line or git gui/gitk, check it out. It makes Git the easiest-to-use VCS ever.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to stay away from cygwin git. I found it unreliable, and making it use an ssh agent like pageant is a nightmare. msysgit and plink is the best combination. Also, don't mess around with line-endings: check out as-is, commit as-is.

As a graphical frontend, I like [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), which comes bundled with msysgit, and is more reliable than TortoiseGit, which is a shell extension that frequently takes down the entire Windows Explorer in flames...

Comment: Indeed, Git Extensions is the best windows client at this point.